# Sentence Structure (linking)

Tags: british-english, commas, syntactic-analysis, dashes

In saying:

> There are a lot of benefits for the new model of transportation, `the Smartcopter`.

How do I name `the model of transportation` as the `Smartcopter` in one sentence as shown in the example above ? Do I use a comma before `The Smartcopter` or a dash or how is it done ? And can I continue the sentence like this:

> ... model of transportation, The Smartcopter, such as it being eco-friendly and ...

this should be in British English.

Comment: Either a comma or a dash is fine to separate the supplementary appositive NP "the Smartcopter".

Comment: We usually say there are benefits ***to*** something, or we speak of the benefits ***of*** doing it. As a noun phrase, *benefits **for** [thing]* doesn't work in any context I can think of offhand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine, although you should not capitalise the 'The'.

**There are a lot of benefits for the new model of transportation, the Smartcopter, such as it being eco-friendly and ...**

Dashes could also be used, but I think commas, in this case, where the sentence is being continued subsequently, would be more usual.